# JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source to Json

Tags: android

I am getting Json Parsing Exception

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CGNotifications>>(){}.getType();
Notifications =gson.fromJson(result,collectionType);
```

Error is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source:


 [{"strNotification":"Hey, Cricgamble has sent you Cash Pack. Play Cricgamble to accept this gift Now…","strNotificationID":"NF73542011530151117256"},


{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF98402011530141552451"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Get Next Wicket : T Dilshan. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF25002011530141551389"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF40702011530141552467"},

{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Take 2 Wickets : R Herath. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 1000 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF40702011530141552467"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Take 2 Wickets : R Herath. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 1000 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF32862011530141552529"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Take 2 Wickets : R Herath. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 1000 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF58272011530141552498"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Take 2 Wickets : R Herath. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 1000 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF90562011530141552514"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Take 2 Wickets : R Herath. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 1000 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF72992011530141552483"},


{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF63272011530141552389"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF98402011530141552451"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF80842011530141552420"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF92422011530141551467"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF74852011530141551436"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF42572011530141551420"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Caught. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF74852011530141551436"},

{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Batsman To Get Out : E Morgan. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF25002011530141551389"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Batsman To Get Out : E Morgan. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF76722011530141550389"},

{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Wicket Method : Bowled. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF57292011530141551404"},

{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Bowler To Get Next Wicket : T Dilshan. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF57292011530141551404"},


{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Batsman To Get Out : E Morgan. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF70732011530141549405"},
{"strNotification":"Opps, you have lost Next Batsman To Get Out : E Morgan. Try your speculation in upcoming matches. CricGamble has withdrawn 100 from your account.","strNotificationID":"NF56012011530141549420"}]
```

to Json

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/ : Checkout following link.

Answer (score 0):

Your json contains a non utf8 characters.
the ellipsis near Now…

If you remove it, it'll compile.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Source you have posted is not correctly formatted, just add property name before your Source. It will run correctly.
So your new source will be

```
    newSource = " { \"propertyName\" : " + oldSource + " } ";
```

and it will work correctly.